# Moment js + angular js firefox date parsing

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i am using moment js with my project and parsing the normal date string for example ("21-jun-2020"). However the parse result is different in chrome and firefox
For chrome

```
_d: Mon Jun 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

For Firefox

```
_d: Date Thu Jun 21 -2021 00:00:00 GMT+0553 (India Standard Time)
```

Is there any way to get a constant result on both the browsers.

Comment: sidenote: Use dayjs, it's alot smaller with the same API... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to UTC to have constant result
`moment("2010-10-20 4:30").utc()`

or using unix timestamp

`var day = moment.unix(1318781876).utc();`

`moment("2010-10-20 4:30").unix()`